# Need a help to perform operation ipv6 ftp server

Tags: java, linux, ftp, ftp-client

I am using linux box.

I am unable do any operation using IPv6 FTP server.I am able to connect using IPV6 FTP server.
But when I will do any operation(like ls,get,put ..) it's giving below exception(Highlighted with bold).

[root@SKP-vlnx ~]# ftp aa01:9:1::22:56ff:231:4b 
Connected to aa01:9:1::22:56ff:231:4b   (aa01:9:1::22:56ff:231:4b  ).
220 Service ready for new user
Name (aa01:9:1::22:56ff:231:4b  ): xyz
331 User name okay, need password for ftp-user
Password:
230 User logged in, proceed
Remote system type is UNIX.

***ftp> ls
502 Command EPSV not implemented
502 Command LPSV not implemented***
Passive mode refused.

Any body please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This means, that the server either does not implement the necessary commands for IPv6 passive mode, which are different from the old IPv4 passive mode (new EPSV, old PASV). This might be either because the server is not really IPv6 ready or because it does not implement passive mode at all.

You might try to use active mode. But, if the server is not really IPv6 ready you will run into the same problem because this also requires a new command for IPv6 (EPRT instead of PORT).